# geom_point smallest point size is not in proportion

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am visualizing a variable using point size.
My problem is that the first (smallest) point size (in this case "70") is significantly (not proportionally) smaller than the rest. (See the legend for CP)

[image: Notice that the point size for "70" is very small]

This is the code I'm using:

```
ggplot(data=testdata, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=ID, size=CP)) + geom_point()
```

On this data:

```
   ID  CP variable value
1  C1  70        A    76
2  C2  95        A    20
3  C3 100        A    30
4  C4  NA        A    17
5  C1  70        B    36
6  C2  95        B    10
7  C3 100        B    51
8  C4  NA        B    41
9  C1  70        C    89
10 C2  95        C     1
11 C3 100        C    94
12 C4  NA        C     6
13 C1  70        D   100
14 C2  95        D    98
15 C3 100        D    16
16 C4  NA        D    33
```

Now, when I'm trying to adjust point sizes R doesn't like it:

```
> testplot = ggplot(data=testdata, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=ID, size=CP)) + geom_point()
> testplot = testplot + scale_size_discrete(range=c(3,5))
Warning message:
Using size for a discrete variable is not advised. 
> testplot
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

And no plot is produced. Same for this:

```
> testplot = ggplot(data=testdata, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=ID, size=CP)) + geom_point()
> testplot = testplot + scale_size_continuous(to=c(3,5))
Error in scale_size_continuous(to = c(3, 5)) : 
  unused argument (to = c(3, 5))
> testplot
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Comment: A workaround: `scale_size(limits = c(1, max(testdata$CP), breaks = unique(testdata$CP))`, but I'm not sure why the defaults aren't working. You can't use a `discrete` size scale for a continuous `size` variable which is why your `scale_size_discrete` doesn't work to fix.

Comment: You are just missing the `range` argument instead of the `to` argument - `scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 5))`.

Comment: Thanks @aosmith indeed `scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 5))` works as expected. I'm still wondering why the first point size is so small unless I specify a range which equals the steps in the legend. Is the categorical nature of the data messing it up? Will I have to adjust the range manually for every graph?

Comment: Your data is not categorical (not in it's `class`, anyway).

Comment: Agree @Gregor that the data is not categorical, however, when I change the data in `CP` to `77 95 84 NA` (and so on) the legend becomes normal – and the plot still has little points, which do not match the legend any more!
[link](https://imgur.com/jvTtVlK)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's an "artefact of human perception" which means the scaling of the points is correct but one might have the impression that it is not. See the developers' discussion [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1666).

The best possible workaround for me is to use `scale_radius(range=c(1, 6))`

Further reading on the relation of perception and scaling: [Stevens' power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevens%27_power_law)

Comment: That is clearly not true in this example --- the point shown as 70 in the question is obviously *far* smaller than 70% of the size of the point shown as 100.  This is not an artefact of human perception.

Comment: @Ben, it is far smaller, and there's a reason behind it. Look at the [discussion](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1666) and particularly [this graph](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4196/17440548/a92a2c02-5af2-11e6-9eb6-16c390d1ade7.png). Non-default scaling options like `scale_radius()` offer alternatives.